# I need to insert a background image in a it else statement without ruining some commands

Tags: javascript

I Have been searching on how to make a background using javascript and all the ways failed including

```
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
```

but it doesn't work and i've been trying to find out why and whenever i put it in a code the prompts and confirms dont work
 ps.the background is in a if then command

is there any way to make the code work

```
    <!doctype html><html><head><script>
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')";
var a = prompt("What Do You Like (Capitalize All Words) (Type In List    To Show List)");
if (a === "List") {
    confirm("Cars,");
    var a = prompt("What Do You Like (Capitalize All Words) (Type In List To     Show List)");
}
if (a === "Cars") {
    var b = prompt("What Type (Capitalize All Words) (Type In “List” To Show     List)");
} else {
    confirm("did not understand");
}




if (b === "List") {
    confirm("Sports Cars,");
    var b = prompt("What Type (Capitalize All Words) (Type In “List” To Show     List)");
}
if (b === "Sports Cars") {
    var c = prompt("What U.S.A. Company (Capitalize All Words)(Type In List To Show List)");
} else {
    confirm("did not understand");
}



if (c === "List") {
    confirm("Bocar,");
    var c = prompt("What U.S.A. Company (Capitalize All Words) (Type In List     To Show List)");
}
if (c === "Bocar") {
    var d = prompt("What Model (Capitalize All Words) (Type In List To Show     List)");
}
if (d === "List") {
    confirm("Stiletto,");
}
if (d === "Stiletto") {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage =
        "url('http://goo.gl/l8Pjl8')";
}
</script></head><body></body></html>
```

thats the whole code   ^^^

Comment: You'll have to post all of the code involved. There is absolutely nothing special to JavaScript about code that updates a style property.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that script tags must be placed in in between the body tags.